# libusb is throwing LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND on libusb_bulk_transfer()

Tags: c, libusb

My problem is that libusb won't transfer a bulk for reading input from my keyboard. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

int main(void)
{

    libusb_init(NULL);

    libusb_device **list;
    libusb_device *found = NULL;
    ssize_t cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &list);
    ssize_t i = 0;

    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    libusb_device_handle *h;

    unsigned char strDesc[128];

    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        libusb_device *device = list[i];
        libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
        if (desc.idProduct == 0x203) {
            libusb_open(device, &h);
            libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(h, desc.iProduct, strDesc, 128);
            printf("=== %s found in host ===\n", strDesc);

            found = device;

            break;
        }
    }

    libusb_device_handle *handle;
    libusb_open(found, &handle);

    unsigned char data[16];
    int act_len;

    libusb_get_device_descriptor(found, &desc);

    int r = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN, data, sizeof(data), &act_len, 0);
    const char *err = libusb_error_name(r);
    printf("%s\n", err);

    libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
    libusb_close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically it loops through all listed devices until it finds my keyboard, with pId 0x203. Then it tries to initiate a `libusb_bulk_transfer()` but at execution time it throws a `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.
Anyone can help me out with this? I have searched but seems that no one has a solution. Thanks!

I am running OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: Keyboards are HID devices, they don't support bulk transfers like, say, a memory stick.  Use libusb_interrupt_transfer() instead.  [Check this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE8QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjanaxelson.com%2Fcode%2Fgeneric_hid.c&ei=LwT7VJPCKIv8yQS1zoHICA&usg=AFQjCNEo8Ryf8ZM6g7KN1eyv7DE3Y6riYw&sig2=aKBuv7RzFy_zzV02F4W5qQ).

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your help. This is my first try with a USB hardware, I should probably get more documented. Anyway, the code you provided appears to be working, but I'm getting a `LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS` now. Tried running it with privileges, but still getting the error.